# change title font of map callouts swift

Tags: swift, font-size, mkannotationview

I would like to know if there is any way to change title font without creating a custom view? Something like this:

```
annotation.title.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12.0)
```

I searched around, everyone says that I have to create a custom view like this [tutorial](http://blog.asynchrony.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/), but it is so complicated and it's in objective-c.

Hope somebody have a simple way to change the font.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible Duplicate that could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118042/custom-font-for-mkannotationview-callout